# How do I get the package length, width, and height in Magento for a shipping estimate?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am looking for a snippet that will give me the length, width, and height of the packaging to ship the items currently in the cart.

I am creating a shipping rates module and this is the last piece of the puzzle.

Any information is greatly appreciated!

Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look @ [Create Shipping Method Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module)

In `collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)` you can get all items using

```
 $request->getAllItems()
```

See /app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Rate/Request.php

So you could Loop through each item to get their dimension

```
foreach($request->getAllItems() as $item){
    //do you logic per item
     $item->getLength();
     $item->getWidth();
     $item->getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work for me, perhaps because it's written 5 years ago and things might have changed a lot since then...

The reason it didn't work because the $item object has no (length, width nor height) returned.

I solved it by re-loading the product using the same $Product object that comes within the $Item object as follows:

```
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $Item)
{

   $ProductID = $Item->getProductId();
   $Product = $Item->getProduct();             // Product Object

   if ($Product)
   {
       $ProductFull = $Product->load($ProductID); // This is the important part, mainly because the original $Product doesn't have the extended attributes loaded, this way we get them all and then you could read any attribute you like without having additional classes on the constructor...

       $W = $ProductFull->getWidth();
       $H = $ProductFull->getHeight();
       $D = $ProductFull->getDepth();

       $WHATEVER = $ProductFull->getWhateverCustomAttributeYouNeed();
   }
}
```

H